# Ethernet cable probably broken but getting DHCP?

Tags: networking, router, ethernet, dhcp

I'm actually trying to troubleshoot an ethernet cable connection.

When I plug it into my windows computer, I get an "Identifying..." infinitely about the connection, and I get no internet connection.

So I'd think that the cable is simply broken, but what makes me doubt is that I get an IP from DHCP... But I can't ping my router (who bring my DHCP address) from this computer, so I'm kinda disappointed...

The IP I get is 192.168.10.xx, so it's a private IP.

My network is simple: Computer - Switch - Router.

Any idea? Thanks for your help!

Comment: what's the ip? 168.x.x.x?

Comment: Editing, the ip is 192.168.10.xx (private ip)

Comment: Does an Ethernet packet capture (Wireshark) actually show your computer sending a DHCP request and receiving the response?

Comment: Will try that right now, gonna tell you the result asap

Comment: It only send a DHCP request in broadcast (255.255.255.255) and get no reply, i'm even more confused now lol